# In Craft CMS CP plugin, how can I get the current entries relevant to the view I'm on? Trying to edit the Lightswitch field for all entries

Tags: plugin-development

In Craft CMS CP plugin development, How can I get the current entries relevant to the view I'm on?

```
Event::on(
   View::class,
   View::EVENT_BEFORE_RENDER,
   function ($context) {
      $entries = someWayToExtractEntriesFromContext($context);
   }
);
```

Or here?

```
Craft::$app->getView()->hook('cp.layouts.base', function(array &$context) {
   $entries = Entry::find()->all();
   // problem with this is it's all entries in all of craft - it's not entries related to the control panel view I'm looking at.
});
```

What I'm trying to do is loop through all entries, and if I see the Lightswitch class modify it.  I want to add a default "off" chandling.  right now the "checked" outputs this:

But unchecked outputs this:

I need unchecked to have additional information.  I also want to add a class to td so I can hook into it better.

Thoughts?  Thanks!